# django cookiecutter project generating error

Tags: django, cookiecutter-django, cookiecutter

I am following the [quickstart](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter-django) of django cookiecutter tutorial. I've installed cookiecutter's latest version and pulled the cookiecutter django repo and the promts were properly filled. But after the last prompt, I always get this error:

**"ERROR: Stopping generation because pre_gen_project hook script didn't exit successfully
Hook script failed (exit status: 1)"**

Honestly, I have no idea what is wrong. Please help :(